# I need help identifying this potentiometer

Tags: amplifier, audio

It is off of a Hifonics mono channel car audio amplifier.

This is the back.  It has 6 prongs and was removed from the gain spot on the amplifier:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need to replace this one does it have to have the same numbes and letters on the back of it or could I use one that has this number and letter on the back that I found on amazon B Type 50K ohm

Comment: thank you for your help so far I am really new to all of this

Comment: It won't hurt anything to use a linear taper pot (B type), but definitely stick with the 50kOhm value.

Comment: thank you for all your help

Comment: The second pic helps, that appears to be a Bourns PTD902 series, or a knockoff thereof.

Comment: just googled it and that's what it is

Comment: VTC as an answer was part of a comment. @TylerStone Please post such comments as answers so we can vote properly, then the post can close normally.

Answer (score 1):

The pot in your photos appears to be very similar to a [Bourns PTD902](https://www.bourns.com/products/potentiometers/commercial-panel-controls/product/PTD90) series unit.

The "A" indicates it is a logarithmic taper (aka Audio taper), and the "503" indicates it is a 50kOhm pot.